# Trying to bundle "rticonnextdds-connector" with Rollup

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle, rollupjs, k6

I am trying to create a simple bundle in which I am trying to bundle the "rticonnextdds-connector" package, and I seem to be struggling. I think it's because of the native node modules. It's not the first time I am using rollup, but I seem to be stuck. All I am trying to do is call the package and export it through an index.js file. But I keep hitting walls. Any help would be appreciated. Needless to say the project is JS, and the node version is flexible.

index.js:

```
const rti = require('rticonnextdds-connector');

console.log(rti);
export let myRTI = rti;
```

I tried many different configurations of the rollup.js file, but none of them seem to work. I think it's because of the native node modules. I really need the entire package to be bundled and not have any external files because I plan to use it inside a k6 script.